# Pandas - syntax of merging data from multiple rows into a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying merge data from multiple rows into a single row with multiple columns. I can only manage one column to work when I want multiple.

Given below is how the data looks like :

```
column1 column2 column3
1       a       Y
1       b       Z
2       d       Z
2       c       Y
```

Expected output:

```
column1 column2 column3
1       a, b       Y, Z
2       d, c       Z, Y
```

Using `df.groupby('column1')['column2'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()` I've got the output:

```
column1 column2 
1       a, b      
2       d, c
```

But unsure the syntax for adding column3.

`df.groupby('column1')['column2', 'column3'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()` doesn't work.

Neither does `df.groupby('column1')[['column2', 'column3']].apply(', '.join).reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `agg` for multiple concatenations:

```
df.groupby('column1').agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()
```